# Manually upload and save files in Carrierwave

Tags: ruby, file-upload, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4, rmagick

I have a directory of existing files which I need to migrate into my rails app as part of a legacy migration. Essentially I need to upload these files manually and save a new record for them in the database. I haven't quite found the proper way to do this. Currently I have the following in a rake task:

```
@attachments.each do |attachment|
  begin
    new_attachment = Attachment.new

    @attachment_file_path = "/home/username/Attachments/" + attachment.Filename
    file = File.open(@attachment_file_path)
    new_attachment[:file] = new_attachment.file.store!(file)

    # Map old record fields to new
    new_attachment.attributes = {
        :project_id => attachment.ProjectID,
        :name => attachment.Description,
        :user_id => attachment.UserId,
        :created_at => attachment.CreatedDate,
        :updated_at => attachment.LastModifiedDate
    }

    new_attachment.save!

    puts "Attachment added successfully "

  rescue => error
    puts "Error migrating Attachment: #{error}"
  end
end
```

**attachment.rb**

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
     mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

**uploader:**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  process :set_content_type
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf doc docx txt)
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [152, nil]
  end

  def default_url
      ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end

  protected
    def image?(new_file)
      if new_file.content_type == nil
        return false
      else
        new_file.content_type.include? 'image'
      end
    end


end
```

This does not work currently. The file never gets uploaded, and occasionally I get the following error:

```
Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: no decode delegate for this image format
```

In this instance, the file is a '.doc' file.

What is the correct way to open a local file and upload it manually via Carrierwave?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
@attachments.each do |attachment|
  begin
    options =  {
        :project_id => attachment.ProjectID,
        :name => attachment.Description,
        :user_id => attachment.UserId,
        :created_at => attachment.CreatedDate,
        :updated_at => attachment.LastModifiedDate,
        :file => File.new(File.join("/home/username/Attachments/",attachment.Filename)) 
    }

     new_attachment = Attachment.new(options)
   

    new_attachment.save!

    puts "Attachment added successfully "

  rescue => error
    puts "Error migrating Attachment: #{error}"
  end
end
```

Perhaps that would do for you as carrierwave would internally call `store!` for you

### Question?

```
Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: no decode delegate for this image format
```

Not sure what are  you trying to over here  because you have define an `image?` method which is not specified in condition also is that something that you want the `content_type` to be only present for `image` file

if `no` perhaps only the process call would work

`process :set_content_type`

if `yes` then perhaps you have to do something like this

```
process :set_content_type , :if => :image?

def image?(new_file)
  %w(jpg jpeg gif).include?(new_file.extension)
end
```

Hope this help

#### EDIT based upon the comment

try this just used the condition same logic

```
   version :thumb ,:if => image? do
     // your code 
   end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I looked and I no longer need the 'image?' method at all, so I removed it. I am still getting the above error even after implementing your changes. I also tried removing 'process set_content_type' and still the same error. How can I prevent 'doc' and text files from being processed by rmagick?